# 'module' object has no attribute 'form_for_model'

Tags: django, django-forms, models

When I am using attribute

form_for_model

I am getting an error module object has not attribute form_for_model..

I created the project from this http://www.mikecantelon.com/?q=node/22

but I am getting the above can any body help me

Comment: Thanx for the reply I create the project from http://www.mikecantelon.com/?q=node/22 but it is showing this error,can u help me out

Answer (score 1):

The post you are referring to is fairly old (2007) and a few things have changed since then:
[form_for_model is deprecated](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-developers@googlegroups.com/msg15650.html).

I'd say you are better off looking at the [official tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) to get started with django.

The current way for creating forms based on models is explained in this part of the docs:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/